# Windows 8.1 slow when out of the domain with internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, domain

I have a laptop with Windows 8.1 Enterprise that I am allowed to take with me and use at home. I am a local administrator on it. The problem that I am having is that when it connect to a working WiFi connection to the Internet. It runs really slow. I am guessing that it is desperately trying to find the My Documents folder which is on a shared folder on one of the domain servers. I have to turn off the WiFi radio everytime I log in to Windows or open any program. When it's done I turn back on the WiFi radio.

Is there a way to lower the timeout or let it know that it's on a public network which is not the home base or something?

Comment: Have you actually confirmed the reason its slow is because its trying to find the shared drives?

Comment: When I open Word for example it pauses for a long time while it looks in my documents folder. As soon as I turn off the WiFi radio it continues normally.

Comment: When you navigate to a *subfolder* of your My Documents folder, what is the full path shown in File Explorer's address bar when you click into it?

Comment: My documents folder is redirected to a shared folder on a network drive.

Answer (score 1):

Get your IT staff to create a local user on the laptop that you can use when you're off the network.  That way it's not looking for domain controllers and networked user directories, etc.

Comment: I have a local admin user in the laptop and it is slow as well while on the Internet.